# How to sort columns in Access datasheet view based on multiple columns?

Tags: ms-access

When I get an output of a query in datasheet view, I know that I can sort any of the column on Ascending or Descending order. However, if I sort one column on ascending/descending order and than the other column on ascending/descending order it will forget about my first asc/desc criteria. I know I can write a query and do order by in multiple fields but it is just faster/easier to just use datasheet view to do this.

Is there a way to sort using multiple columns in the datasheet view?

Answer (score 1):

**How to sort multiple columns in datasheet view?**

Open the data in datasheet view.
In the Home tab, navigate to the "Sort & Filter" section and click on Advanced.
Next, select Advanced Filter/Sort.
This will open a new query in design view.
Select the appropriate fields and appropriate sorting.
When done, navigate again to the "Sort & Filter" section, click on Advanced and select Apply Filter/Sort.
Close the new query (do not save).

Answer (score 0):

Mark (select) two or more columns and select the sorting from the ribbon or right-click.

You can, however, not mix *asc* and *desc* across the columns. It is either of these for all columns marked.

Comment: How do you select 2 or more column? Holding ctrl key does not let me do it. Holding shift works but it will select all the columns between the columns that I want selected

Comment: You can't. The selected columns must be juxtaposed.